# php/mysql update set query throwing an error

Tags: php, mysql

So I've spent way too long trying to figure out why my code isn't working and throwing this error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET botteam = (SELECT 'winner' FROM games WHERE id='6'), SE' at line 3

What I've been trying to do is take the winner from id (`$i`) and place it as the "topteam" in a row at (`$p`) id position.

I'm also trying to get the winner, see if it equals the "topteam" and carry the "topseed" from that row to the same "topseed" position at row (`$p`). lternatively, if the winner does not equal "topteam" then I want to carry the "botseed" to the "topseed" position at row (`$p`) instead. And then that is running again for the "botseed" position at row (`$p`). I'm fairly new at this so I'm sure there's a much nicer way to write this but this is where I'm at right now.

Here is my table

| id | topseed | botseed | topteam | botteam | winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | Team A | Team B | Team A |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | Team C | Team D | Team D |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |

Here is what I want my table to look like after the query is complete

| id | topseed | botseed | topteam | botteam | winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | Team A | Team B | Team A |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | Team C | Team D | Team D |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | Team A | Team D |  |

Here is my code

```
UPDATE games
                SET topteam = (SELECT 'winner' FROM games WHERE id='$i'),
                SET botteam = (SELECT 'winner' FROM games WHERE id='$k'),
                SET topseed = (SELECT 'topseed' FROM games WHERE 'winner' = 'topteam' AND id='$i'),
                SET topseed = (SELECT 'botseed' FROM games WHERE 'winner' = 'botteam' AND id='$i'),
                SET botseed = (SELECT 'topseed' FROM games WHERE 'winner' = 'topteam' AND id='$k'),
                SET botseed = (SELECT 'botseed' FROM games WHERE 'winner' = 'botteam' AND id='$k'),
                WHERE id = '$p'"
```

My code is running through a for loop so the ids are dynamic and will run through the entire table.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Although at this point, 5 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial would be useful

Comment: I tried reformatting and it pulled the same error. Thanks for your generosity and kind words! <3

Comment: you have an incorrect SQL syntax, please carefully look at the syntax, no multiple SET https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question by troubleshooting some more. Here is the code I ended up with if anyone was interested.

```
UPDATE games dt1, games dt2, games dt3 
                SET dt1.topteam = dt2.winner, dt1.botteam = dt3.winner,
                dt1.topseed = (IF(dt2.winner = dt2.topteam OR dt2.winner = dt2.botteam, (IF(dt2.winner = dt2.topteam, dt2.topseed, dt2.botseed)), NULL)),
                dt1.botseed = (IF(dt3.winner = dt3.topteam OR dt3.winner = dt3.botteam, (IF(dt3.winner = dt3.topteam, dt3.topseed, dt3.botseed)), NULL))
                WHERE dt1.id = '$p' AND dt2.id = '$j' AND dt3.id = '$k'
```